# Show widget location borders for development

Tags: plugins, widgets

I'm taking over a wordpress site, whose template has a high number of widget locations in the appearance section.

Is there a way to temporarily turn on the widget location borders so I know where they are at for follow Ono development.

Hoopla has this ability by adding a ?t=1 or something like that to the end of the url.  Does Wordpress have something like that also?

Thanks.

Comment: [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)

Comment: [Chrome Dev Tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools)

Answer (score 0):

If your theme is any good, no code at all will be rendered for empty widget areas, so if you want them all to show, you must populate them.

There are off course browser tools that will highlight widget areas, but they will only show one at a time, while you presumably want an overview of all areas on your site. There's no built in method for this, but it's not difficult to make.

Since this is only temporary you can be forgiven for adding a line to the `header.php` file just before the `<body>` tag, where you should see a statement `body_class($variable)`. Here you include:

```
if (current_user_can('edit_themes')) $variable .= " widget-borders".
```

Effectively this adds the class 'widget-borders' to the body. Then, in the code, find the class that is used for widget areas, let's say "my-widget". Now you have enough information to target widget areas just for admins with css, by adding this line to `style.css`:

```
body.widget-borders .my-widget {border:2px solid red;}
```